# Does nocturnal emission due to wet dreams break fast?

Tags: sawm, nocturnal-emission

What should person do if during fasting while sleeping experience [nocturnal emission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission).

Comment: those occur only at night & at night no one fasts.

Comment: @Ashu can happen at noon while taking a nap. But the question is important from both the occasions.

Comment: also can happen when you sleep and you wake up after dawn which is fairly common :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wet dreams do not invalidate Sawm (Fast) or Hajj because it is beyond human control.

Allah says in Qur'an:

> Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. [**[Surah Al-Baqarah 2:286](http://quran.com/2/286)**]

However, you should perform Ghusl if sperm is ejaculated.

**Source:** [Wet dreams- Fasting](http://www.alifta.com/Fatawa/Fatwaprint.aspx?id=45&BookID=10&sectionid=)

Answer (score 1):

It does not invalidate the fast. You should perform a ghusl immediately after waking up.